# How to write 'username' on a dashboard page ? Nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, handlebars.js

I made a login system, when user login I want to write his username on the dashboard.

I try that :

```
<h2 class="page-header">Dashboard</h2>
<p>Welcome to your dashboard {{username}}</p>
```

but its not working

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    // VALIDATION
    req.checkBody('name','Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('username','Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password','Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);
)}
```

What can I do ?

Comment: I don't know how your render your html, do your use any framework? I'm not sure Nodejs is made to render html. Anyway, your `username` variable is only defined withing your anonymous function, not outside.

Comment: i have bodyparser express mongodb flashconnect

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to render the view with the username as a local variable.This can be done using express res.render() function.
Eg : `res.render('view',{username: ''});`.You can check out this documentation for better understanding - https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render